# Customisable tableview cell swipe to stop on full expansion?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swipe-gesture

Is there any way to easily achieve the results in the pictures below (maybe by using MGSwipeTableCell or SwipeCellKit or any other pod you know of). I'm pretty sure you can't do that using the default iOS UIKit.

There are 2 things here to consider:

1) The table view cell swipe actions, should be completely customisable (putting an UIView there, so you can put anything you want inside the UIView) or at least, get closer to the screenshot, using 1 and then 5 buttons (therefore, different swipe-actions for smallswipe and fullswipe) ?

2) The tableview cell swipe action, must first (small-swipe) only show the "alarm' icon like in the first picture, and if you click on it, or swipe even further it should look like in the second picture, and most importantly, stay like that, no auto-unswiping (no action to be done, except waiting for input from user, to either select another cell, or any of the buttons there).

I'm not asking for a complete solution, I just want to know if it's possible and relatively easy to do, so I won't waste weeks in order to try to achieve this and find out in the end that it's not possible.

[SmallSwipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joiU2.png)

[FullSwipeOrClick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2Iak.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in you tableCell, you can add view to contentView, that will be fill all cell and drag it via UIPanGestureRecognizer. Your action views will be under scrollable view. Something like this:

```
class SwipableTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var actionView: UIView // under mainView
    @IBOutlet var mainView: UIView // take whole place of contentView
    @IBOutlet var panGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer

    @IBAction func panAction(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // drag main view left or right and logic of auto swiping 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is something new, I didn't knew you could do this with PanGesture... I'll try this and come back here with the results. If indeed you can drag the mainView despite constraints and autolayout, then this surely is possible and easy.

Comment: Thank you, this PanGestureRecognizer was exactly the thing I wanted, now I have full power over everything. I will mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know if you can make a small and full swipe native. The method for swipe for iOS 11 is [tableView(_:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/2902367-tableview).

From there, I know there is [performFirsActionWithFullSwipe](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipeactionsconfiguration/2902361-performsfirstactionwithfullswipe), that doesn't allow full swipe on the first time. I think you can play with this two. In configuration you can add UIContextualAction that has an action, image and even background color that you can set.

I hope it helps.